# Keras: convert pretrained weights between theano and tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, theano, keras

I would like to use [this pretrained model](https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3).

It is in theano layout, my code depends on tensorflow image dimension ordering.

There is a guide on [converting weights between the formats](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/wiki/Converting-convolution-kernels-from-Theano-to-TensorFlow-and-vice-versa).

But this seems broken. In the section to convert theano to tensorflow, the first instruction is to load the weights into the tensorflow model.

> Keras backend should be TensorFlow in this case.
>   First, load the Theano-trained weights into your TensorFlow model:

```
model.load_weights('my_weights_theano.h5')
```

This raises an exception, the weight layouts would be incompatible.
And if the `load_weights` function would take theano weights for a tensorflow model, there wouldn't be any need to convert them.

I took a look at the [`convert_kernel`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/np_utils.py) function to see, whether I could do the necessary steps myself.

The code is rather simple - I don't understand why the guide makes use of a tensorflow session. That seems unnecessary.

I've copied the code from the pretrained model to create a model with tensorflow layer. This just meant changing the input shape and the `backend.image_dim_ordering` before adding any Convolutions.
Then I used this loop:

`model` is the original model, created from the code I linked at the beginning.
`model_tensorflow` is the exact same model, but with tensorflow layout.

```
for i in range(len(model.layers)):
    layer_theano=model.layers[i]
    layer_tensorflow=model_tensorflow.layers[i]

    if layer_theano.__class__.__name__ in ['Convolution1D', 'Convolution2D', 'Convolution3D', 'AtrousConvolution2D']:
        weights_theano=layer_theano.get_weights()

        kernel=weights_theano[0]
        bias=weights_theano[1]

        converted_kernel=convert_kernel(kernel, "th")
        converted_kernel=converted_kernel.transpose((3,2,1,0))

        weights_tensorflow=[converted_kernel, bias]

        layer_tensorflow.set_weights(weights_tensorflow)

    else:
        layer_tensorflow.set_weights(layer_theano.get_weights())
```

In the original code, there is a testcase: Prediction ran on the image of a cat.
I've downloaded a cat image and tried the testcase with the original model: 285.
The converted model predicts 585.

I don't know whether 285 is the correct label for a cat, but even if it isn't, the two models should be broken in the same way, I would expect the same prediction.

What is the correct way of converting weights between models ?

Comment: Any updates? Have you seen https://github.com/titu1994/Keras-Classification-Models ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The code is broken. As of now, there is a work around for this issue and the solution is described [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5374#issuecomment-279256632).

I have tested it myself and it worked for me.

If you feel the answer is useful, please upvote it. Thanks!