# KERAS: Converting convolutional kernels from theano to tensorflow, OOM

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a real problem with converting Keras model's convolutional kernels and most preferably dense weights (but that is not my priority) from theano to tensorflow. I made some research but I just can't handle it. First I used this script:
[Keras: convert pretrained weights between theano and tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193436/keras-convert-pretrained-weights-between-theano-and-tensorflow)

But than my accuracy fell from 85% to worse than random (12% in 8 classes) so I guess something is wrong with it.

Than I tried to use titu1994 code aka: https://github.com/titu1994/Keras-Classification-Models/blob/master/weight_conversion_theano.py

Although I just can't get it done because I get error during the script about running OOM on my paperspace virtual machine and I can't get access to better one. The weights are vgg16_bn.h5 from fast.ai deep learning course. I would highly appreciate any help if you had similiar problem before or maybe if some1 had converted these weights to tensorflow format I would love if you decide to share.

Or if you know other weights and models I can succesfully perform transfer learning from I would appreciate if you share as well.

Comment: Is your runtime environment Keras 2 or Keras 1?

Comment: My enviroment is Keras 2, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In Keras 2, the conversion of convolutional kernels is performed automatically in `load_weights()`. In your case, the automatic conversion failed because you're trying to load a Keras 1 weight file, and there's no backend information saved in Keras 1 weight files.

So all you need to do is to put an attribute named `backend` into the weight file, and let Keras take care of the rest.

```
import h5py
with h5py.File(weight_file, 'a') as f:
    f.attrs['backend'] = 'theano'.encode('utf8')
```